# how to take mysql backup using vb.net code

Tags: vb.net, mysql-workbench

I want to take a backup from mysql workbench using vb.net. I am using MySql Workbench 5.2 CE. and below is my code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        '        
        Process.Start("C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe", " -u root -p mypass  dbname -r ""C:\dbname.sql""")
End Sub
```

but after running my project it makes the sound "beep" but no backup is created... Please provide me the correct solution.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I just want to take backup from mysql from vb.net.